# SSIS Flat File Destination - Columns going out of sync when adding new column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

Really hoping someone can help me with this 2008 SSIS BIDS issue. I am very new to the software so I am hoping it will be something simple!

I am attempting to use SSIS to retrieve data from an SQL table. My data flow consists of one OLE DB Source pointing directly to one Flat File Destination.

At the moment I can successfully retrieve 4 columns which display fine however when I attempt to add a fifth column (from data returned from SQL database) it appears to jumble everything up.

To elaborate the fifth column should contain a letter between “A – F” however instead of pulling this through from my results in the OLE Data Source it appears to be pulling through data from columns 1 – 4

EG before adding this extra column things look like this:

```
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|
| Column 1 |Column2     |Column3      |Column4 |
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|
|444456654 |10/01/2015  |User unable  |JSMIT14 |
|          |            |to logout of |        |
|          |            |app without  |        | 
|          |            |crashing.    |        |
------------------------------------------------
```

However after adding the end column and mapping it accordingly everything seems to go out of sync, with added quotation marks:

```
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------------------|
| Column 1 |Column2     |Column3      |Column4 |Column 5               |
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------------------|
|444456654 |10/01/2015  |User unable  |JSMIT14 |444456654”,”User       |
|          |            |to logout of |        |unable to logout of    |
|          |            |app without  |        |app without            |
|          |            |crashing.    |        |crashing.”,”JSMITH14   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was expecting it to pull through the data as I had mapped it and appear as below:

```
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|---------|
| Column 1 |Column2     |Column3      |Column4 |Column 5 |
|----------|------------|-------------|--------|---------|
|444456654 |10/01/2015  |User unable  |JSMIT14 | F       |
|          |            |to logout of |        |         |
|          |            |app without  |        |         |
|          |            |crashing.    |        |         |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I add the extra column by selecting “Flat File Connection Manager”  > “Advanced” > “New”.

I then map the SQL column to my new column by selecting “Flat File Destination”  > “Mappings”

- Please note if I select the data source and preview the SQL code all appears fine so I feel that something must be going wrong at the Flat File Destination stage.

Comment: what do you want in newly added column... is it a sum of other two columns?

Comment: Hi Koushik, it's literally mapped to a column returned from the OLE Data source. No addition or anything required.

Comment: How you are assigning A-F in new column

Comment: So in the same way that columns 1-4 are mapped to the Flat File Destination I added the columns in the flat file connections manager by selecting it, clicking advanced then new column. I then map it to the columns returned in the OLE Data Source.
The OLE Data Source contains and SQL query returning numerous columns, of which I map to flat file destination for output.

Comment: - A - F is returned in a column that is returned from the database in the SQL query. I am mapping it to the Flat File Destination to output as a text file.

Comment: remove your connection manager and add flatfile dest.... then open flatfile and add connection manager as new and create new maager..it will wrk.

Comment: Did you try deleting your data input arrow from the OLEDB source and reconnecting it to the Flat File?  Sometimes the metadata gets wonky after changes...

Comment: Thanks guys it appears to be somekind of display issue. The file actually exports fine and all in sync. When I close the application and load it again it does sometimes appear OK in app but then gets jumbled up again, very strange! I'm happy though as the export is working fine!